# Django cache does not get refreshed

Tags: django, caching

I've added a simple caching to my web application and when I delete or add new object the cache does not get refreshed after the peroid of time (2 minutes) that I've set.

It looks like it froze. When I restart my application then it gets refreshed.

I tried it on memached and locmemcache.

```
INDEX_LIST_CACHE_KEY = "index_list_cache_key"

class IndexView(BaseView):
    queryset = Advert.objects.all().select_related('category', 'location')[:25]
    template_name = "adverts/category_view.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = cache.get(INDEX_LIST_CACHE_KEY)
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.queryset
            cache.set(INDEX_LIST_CACHE_KEY, queryset, 2 * 60)
        return queryset
```

Why caching behaves like that in this project?

Edit - settings.py:

for locmemcache

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'oglos-cache'
    }
}
```

for memcached

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your cache-related settings from `settings.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by slicing the queryset in the class definition, you've evaluated it then and there - at class definition time, ie when the server starts up. So the cache is being refreshed, but only with an old set of items. Don't do that slice at class level: do it when returning the results from `get_queryset`.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! :) I would never have found that out or probably it would take ages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by forcing django to not cache my view:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_path', cache_page(0)(views.MyViewList.as_view()), name='view-list')
]
```