# Django cache and pagination

Tags: django, caching, pagination

I have a paginated view(SubmissionsLazyload below) which does not gets updated as expected because of unwanted caching.

**Views.py**

```
class PublisherDetailViewCat(ListView):
    template_name = "recent_submi.html"
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qset = CEntry.objects.filter(active=True)
        return qset


class SubmissionsLazyload(PublisherDetailViewCat):
    template_name = "snippets/submissions_lazy_load.html"
```

cache setting  in settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'iso-cache'
    }
}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY=True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'profiles.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

Below is how i get over the issue currently, Is there any  way to enable cache and use paginated view at the same time.?

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache


class SubmissionsLazyload(PublisherDetailViewCat):
    template_name = "snippets/submissions_lazy_load.html"
    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SubmissionsLazyload, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Django version is 1.4.1 tested both in python 2.6.5 and 2.7

Comment: I have seen a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599946/django-cache-does-not-get-refreshed. But in my case i am not using slice.

Comment: I assume that the caching is done along the GET params, so when a newer entry arrives then that is not in the result